# Returning maps data structures

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm trying to work out how to return a map when calling a function in Go. I can't seem to find anything documented anywhere on this. This is what I've tried so far:

```
func test() map {
// Get Auth Token (POST https://192.168.13.234/aperture/api/users/authorize)
anotherMap := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d"}
return anotherMap
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return map type must be fully defined.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/26LFrBhpBC

```
func test() map[string]string {
    anotherMap := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d"}
    return anotherMap
}
```